# How to remove the Table of Contents from the Table of Contents in WKHTMLTOPDF in java?

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf

I have created a pdf from html and it shows duplicate entry toc as

```
     Table of contents

table of contents    2
some page            3
some page            4
```

I am doing it in java.

Now i want to remove this extra table of contents that is coming up in list.
A lot of articles have suggested to edit the default xsl and edit it but i am not aware of how to do it.

Is there a way i can manipulate my toc through java code?
Please guide!